# When to use a vertex array and when to use a VBO?

Tags: opengl

I'm trying to learn about **vertex arrays** and **vertex buffer objects**, but I don't understand the differences in terms of:

- case-of-use (static geometry like terrains, geometry that changes every frame like a particle system, etc.)
- performance
- portability (old graphics card, consoles, devices like Android or iPhone, etc.)

some clarifications?

Comment: For anyone else that arrives here, check out the most up voted answer here.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/430555/when-are-vbos-faster-than-simple-opengl-primitives-glbegin

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Here](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Buffer_Objects) is a decent writeup about VBOs.

**Performance**

[Here](https://web.archive.org/web/20100624134218/http://ezekiel.vancouver.wsu.edu/%7Ecs442/lectures/vbo/vbo.pdf) is a good overview of the calling semantics.

[Here](https://web.archive.org/web/20120202172037/http://developer.amd.com/media/gpu_assets/PerformanceTuning.pdf) here is another good overview of performance issues; in it we see that VBOs are more performant than arrays.

The reason we prefer VBOs is that the data is loaded onto the card, and so you don't have to transfer it every frame. Depending on the type of VBO created, you can give the graphics driver hints on the usage (write-many, read-many vs. write-many, never-read, etc).

**Usage**

VBOs are really good for static geometry like terrain that you don't expect to change, or for instanced geometry.

Vertex arrays are good for data that changes frequently but that also is read by the host machine--so, for directly rendering data that is being manipulated (laser rangefinder data buffers, for example, are where I've used them) frequently. If you can get away with never reading the data on the host device (so, just pushing it out onto the card), VBOs in write-only mode are a good option.

**Portability**

*Client Side Vertex Arrays*
These are available in OpenGL prior to 3.0, deprecated in 3.0, and gone in 3.1+.
OpenGL ES supports them (OpenGL ES 2 does not).

*VBOs*
These are available after OpenGL 1.5.
These are the only way to store geometry data in OpenGL ES 2 (and so, WebGL).

Comment: I'm pretty sure OpenGL ES 2 does support vertex arrays. They use them in "OpenGL ES 2.0 Programming Guide", also see section 2.8 in the spec: http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/specs/2.0/es_full_spec_2.0.25.pdf

Comment: In that PerformanceTuning.pdf, it says that VBOs "Can hurt performance in non-optimal cases"... but it doesn't elaborate. Any idea what those cases are? I have a case where I need to update the geometry every frame, so I'm wondering if a vertex array would be better or worse than a VBO in that case. Thx.

Comment: read http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glDrawElements.xml and http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GlDrawElements - Vertex Arrays AREN'T deprecated nor removed, they are still supported as of OpenGL 4.x; get your facts straight, mate, because what you're spreading is just misinformation

Comment: @vaxquis Client side vertex arrays are deprecated. Server side vertex arrays are not. VAOs are different thing and are meant to save state. Nothing was wrong in the post, though could be more accurate if it state client side. But I guess that was implicit.

Comment: Client side arrays are deprecated. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11806823/glenableclientstate-deprecated Yet glDrawElements is still used to draw server side vertex/index arrays. On the other hands VAOs have nothing to do with storage, and it's only there to save states of server side vertex arrays.

Comment: "Client side vertex arrays are deprecated. Server side vertex arrays are not."

"Vertex Arrays These are available in OpenGL prior to 3.0, deprecated in 3.0, and gone in 3.1+."

"you can prespecify separate arrays of vertices (...) and use them to construct a sequence of primitives with a single call to glDrawElements. Core in version  4.4"

- I see contradiction in these statements.

Comment: Plus, before saying something "is deprecated", specify the source of such statement, preferably in official document. Pointing from StackExchange to StackOverflow as a proof is NOT the way science works, and defending with "I guess that was implicit" is not an argument. Nobody asked about client/server arrays, the question was about vertex array in the broadest sense, as compared to VBO. Btw, I haven't said anything about VAO, where's that idea from?

Comment: quote from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8827926/glenableclientstate-and-glenablevertexattribarray "The main reason for replacing glEnableClientState with glEnableVertexAttribArray is, that since OpenGL-3 always uses vertex arrays" - that said, do you understand that an answer to the question about _vertex arrays_ deserves to either state that we _still_ use vertex arrays and the distinction is between C/S usage or just assume we're talking about vertex arrays in general? saying that vertex array is deprecated by VBO is like saying Java had deprecated pointers in favor of references.

Comment: Please take further commentary on this issue to [chat]. Comments are not for extended discussion; resolve whatever issues need resolution in the chat and edit the question accordingly.

Comment: Although it has been a year, I just wanted to note that ChrisE is talking about OpenGL ES (Not open GL). And his statement is indeed correct. In GL ES (Light version for mobile), vertex arrays are deprecated in version 3.0.

Answer (score 11):

(I'm adding this here due to the the fact that ChrisE's answer is highly ambiguous, which is unfortunately due to the ambiguity of the original question. However I'm going to assume the OP's question should have been titled "when to use **VAOs** and when to use **VBOs**".)

**V**ertex **B**uffer **O**bjects (which really aren't dissimilar from other types of **B**uffer **O**bjects, for example **U**niform **B**uffer **O**bjects) provide a means for uploading vertex data to the graphics hardware.

**V**ertex **A**rray **O**bjects are used in addition to **VBO**s in order to improve client-side (CPU-side) performance, by reducing the number of calls needed to rebind individual vertex buffers and re-set vertex attributes every time you want to change to render in a certain way. Instead of doing all that work every frame, you do it once (at initialisation), and then simply rebind the appropriate **VAO** for each (set of) draw call(s) that use the associated vertex attributes.

In spite of this, using **VAOs** does not release you from the additional responsibility of having to do `glBindBuffer` + `glBufferData` for any data that *changes* each frame, for instance, game entity positions / rotations / transform matrices. It is only when you have entirely static data that you need only do `glBindVertexArray(&vao) -> glDraw*(...) -> glBindVertexArray(0)` to render.

Comment: +1 VAO is a terrible and confusing name, and it always reminds me of what a mess openGL has become.

Comment: I also remember going with a discussion regarding this question (most of it was deleted). Again the problem is with OpenGL's horrible terminology. I also edited Chris answer to be more accurate.

Answer (score -2):

In short words VBO is an array of raw data, when VAO is an array of ATTRIBUTES - an instruction for shader program how to use the data.

VBO allows to keep data on GPU side, which saves transfer time, you just need to know VBO's id.

But VBO by itself is not enough. You have to instruct GPU how to use it. You have to define "Vertex Attribute Pointers" (command glVertexAttribPointer) for each attribute (input data variable) of your shader. Before VAO you had to define attributes for each glDrawArrays call (it's a lot), in every frame (like 30+ times per second). VAO allows to attach an entire array of attributes by just VAO's id. So, when VBO is relatively independent, the VAO is VBO+shader-specific.

Comment: Although this appears to be relevant about VAO and VBO, it does not seem to address any of the concerns described in the question.

Comment: Thank you for explanation, appreciated.
Absolutely reasonable rule, didn't mean to break it.
The post is fixed.